# Passing for loop vars to new function

Tags: python

I'm struggling to pass a variable to a separate function. What is missing from the below?

```
import sys, os, locale
from workflow import Workflow, ICON_WEB, web
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def main(wf):

    url = 'https://digitallibrary.un.org/search?ln=en&p=A/72/490&f=&rm=&ln=en&sf=&so=d&rg=50&c=United+Nations+Digital+Library+System&of=xm&fti=0&fti=0'
    r = web.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()
    root = ET.fromstring(r.content)

    for record in root:
        symbol = record.find("{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}datafield[@tag='191']/{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}subfield[@code='a']").text
        report_title = record.find("{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}datafield[@tag='245']/{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}subfield[@code='a']").text
        wf.add_item(title=report_title,subtitle=symbol,icon=ICON_WEB)

    wf.send_feedback()

if __name__ == u"__main__":
    wf = Workflow()
    sys.exit(wf.run(main))
```

This returns a `local variable references before assignment`.

Comment: btw don't use variable names like `set`, because python uses this as a type. The same with `list`, `str`, `dict` and others.

Comment: If `set` or `set2` are empty, then those variables will never be defined since the loop will never run

Comment: Thank you, all! I must fail to understand the scoping rules. I'm reading the material you shared, dear @G.Anderson, but I am missing something here.

I found a way to simplify parts of the code and avoid the for loops altogether, but the issue seems to be in terms of how the variables are passed on to a function from the alfred-workflow package (`wf.add_item`). It must be trivial...

Comment: The edited code is very different from what you initially posted, so my previous comment is no longer be relevant. Please provide the full error traceback, rather than just the last line. The code does not make a [mcve], as `wf` is not defined

Comment: One thought I see is `report_title` vs `record_title` as defined variables

Comment: where do you initialize `report_title` before you reference it as an argument in your `wf.add_item` call?

Comment: It seems this question has been edited *significantly* from its original form. Does the currently shown code even still have an error? If so, which one exactly? Please include the entire traceback when reporting errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed removing the for loop resolved the original issue and with the fix by G. Anderson the code is now workable.